# How do I provide default YAML configuration values in a static library?

Tags: c++, configuration, yaml, default, default-value

I have a configuration file system written in C++ which uses the yaml-cpp library to parse and write to YAML files. I have this as part of my static library.

I would like the ability to return a default value for a field that is requested by a user of the library (calling from their code), but which has not been defined in the user's YAML file.

For example say the user wants to use the field `foo` from their custom `config.yaml` file:

```
int bar = config_reader.read<int>( "config.yaml", "foo" );
```

If they have `foo: 10` in their `config.yaml` then `bar` will be set to 10. However I would also like to provide a default value (for example 4) in the case where `foo` is omitted from `config.yaml`.

There are two possibilities I have thought of:

1. Have a set of static maps between field names and default values in a cpp file which gets compiled into the static library, however I will need to have different maps for different types and I feel this could get messy with type checking and maybe requiring template specialization methods.
2. Have a YAML file which contains all of the default values for expected fields, which the configuration system falls back on if it cannot find the field in the user's config file. I think this would be the preferred solution for me, but I cannot think of a neat way of packaging this YAML file. I would rather the user didn't have to copy or point to this file each time they set up a new project linking the static library.

Comment: Is this OS independent? If on Linux put the defaults in `/etc/default/YOURLIBNAME.yaml` and override with values from `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/YOURLIBNAME/config.yaml` or (if XDG_CONFIG_HOME not set, `$HOME/YOURLIBNAME/config.yaml`) . I would just error out if some deletes the `foo` field from the global config file. If on Windows probably should use `%APPDATA%`

Comment: Yes it is for a LInux system.

This makes a lot of sense and seems easy enough to implement. Thanks!

Comment: The alternative if XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set should be `$HOME/.config/YOURLIBNAME/config.yaml` ( I forgot the `.config`). Shall I make this an answer?

Comment: Yes, seems like the appropriate answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would provide the defaults in a YAML file in a global (i.e. non-user specific place) and allow to override the values with user-specific ones. 
Consider just throwing an error if the global defaults are missing an entry, this will not happen by accident.

The global defaults you can put in `/etc/default/YOUBLIBNAME.yaml`. The user's configuration nowadays mostly follows the [XDG](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.6.html) base directory specification. For that use `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/YOURLIBNAME/config.yaml` if `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is set in the environment, if not set use `$HOME/.config/YOURLIBNAME/config.yaml`.

If your library has to work under Windows, I would put the user specific data under `%APPDATA%` in a subdir `YOURBLINAME`.